# R count instances in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to avoid a for loop here. I have a data frame that looks like this

```
sample1,[species 1],[species 2],[species 1]
sample2,[species 3],[species 2],[species 4]
sample3,[species 6],[species 5]
sample3,[species 6],[species 5],[species 7],[species 5]
etc.
```

The number of columns is not equal in each sample. I want to count the number of species total. However, species only count as separate if they are in different samples. For example, species 1 occurs only 1 time, not 2 times. Species 5 should occur 2 times, not 3.

Here is the code that I have that currently counts 1 column:

```
counts <- data.frame(table(str_extract(tolower(df[,column]), "\\[(.*?)\\]")))
```

Hopefully that makes sense. I can edit the question if there is any confusion. 
Thanks!

Comment: How did you make a data.frame with a different number of columns for each row? Are the rows just padded with NA values?

Comment: Can you please `dput` a few rows of your data frame?

Comment: I read the data in with this code: `fields <- max(count.fields(file, sep = ','), na.rm = TRUE); df <- read.csv(file, header=FALSE, col.names = paste0("V", seq_len(fields)), fill = TRUE)`

Comment: Dput is a little bit unwieldy on my dataset, but here you go: https://gist.github.com/arundurvasula/1729dc63e02e534bb045

Comment: By "a few rows", I didn't mean 7136 rows of `dput`ing

Comment: Sorry, I did `dput(head(df), file)` and uploaded the file but it still seems like too much.

Comment: @ohblahitsme, I would *guess* that your `dput` would be a bit smaller if you did not read in all of your strings as factors.